# Bootstrap node and its permission

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

If we want to connect to **regular node** then we have to go through **bootstrap** node ? What in the case of **private chain** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide bootstrap nodes in geth with the `--bootnodes` option. If it is already running you can use command `admin.addPeer()` to add new peers.

You can read more details in the wiki page [How to setup a Private network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network).

Comment: I am not talking about its properties . I am asking about its process and work.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what do you mean with "process and work"? Are you asking [how do bootnodes works?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3918u0/how_does_the_p2p_network_on_ethereum_work/) Ethereum does works the same in mainnet and a private network, the only difference is that mainenet have some parameters hardcoded.